# Check if a user is an admin in a setup function

Tags: discord.js

I would like to make a setup function to put my bot up, but it has to be usable ONLY by admins.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("!setup")) {
  if (message.auther.admin) {
    //my code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if that user has the 'Administrator' permission just use this:

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.reply('No Perms!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your admin role is named "Admin", the following code should do what you're wanting:

```js
const adminRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name == "Admin");

if (message.member.roles.has(adminRole.id)) {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!setup")) {
        //setup command code
    }
} else {
    message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permission to use this command!").catch(console.error);
}
```

You'll want the `if` statement for the admin check to be first, that way you can define all of your administrative commands within it. Otherwise, if you have more than one admin-only command you would have to have the admin check multiple times.